# Is it possible to create a C# 'pointer' to a DateTime object?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a C# pointer to a DateTime object?  I'm trying to do this:

```
DateTime Event1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime Event2 = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10);

DateTime EventPointer;  // A Pointer?

if (something)
{
  EventPointer = Event1;
}
else
{
  EventPointer = Event2;
}

EventPointer.DoSomething? //  Something that would change the value of Event1/2 variable.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly, but you can wrap it around a class:

```
Wrapper w1 = new Wrapper { TheDate = DateTime.Now };
Wrapper w2 = new Wrapper { TheDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10) };

Wrapper w;
if (something)
{
    w = w1;
}
else
{
    w = w2;
}

w.DoSomething();

class Wrapper
{
    public DateTime TheDate { get; set; }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I somehow assumed that DateTime was a class, not a struct.

Answer (score 1):

DateTimes are value types which unlike reference types everytime you assign its value to another variable their value is copied.

Answer (score 1):

A `DateTime` is a value type, when you assign it the value is copied. However, methods can take a reference to a value type using the `ref` keyword. Your EventPointer.DoSomething would take a DateTime as reference. Here's a simple example of how you might be able to apply it.

```
var date = DateTime.Today;
MakeMinValue(ref date);
Console.Out.WriteLine("date = {0}", date);

public void MakeMinValue(ref DateTime dateTime)
{
    dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

This will only work with a method parameter.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't use pointers in managed code unless you use `unsafe`. I'd advise against it.
2. DateTimes are immutable. The only thing you can do to modify a variable of type DateTime is to reassign to it.

You can do something *close* to what you want, but in general it's not a good idea to do this:

```
DateTime event1 = new DateTime(2011, 10, 11);
DateTime event2 = new DateTime(2021, 10, 11);

Action<DateTime> eventPointer;  // A Pointer?

if (true)
{
    eventPointer = x => { event1 = x; };
}
else
{
    eventPointer = x => { event2 = x; };
}

eventPointer(new DateTime(2016, 10, 11));

Console.WriteLine(event1.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine(event2.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Result:

```
10/11/2016 00:00:00
10/11/2021 00:00:00
```

I think it is a better idea is to find another way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers, as you are thinking of them, don't exist in managed C# code.  You might want to look into `out` and `ref` parameters if you need to pass a DateTime and have the original value change.  Since DateTimes are structs (value type) they are always copied instead of passed by reference, unless you specifically use an `out` or `ref` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace type of `EventPointer`, `Event1` and `Event2` types from `DateTime` type to `DateTime?`. It makes EventPointer's type nullable reference type.

```
DateTime? Event1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime? Event2 = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10);

DateTime? EventPointer;  

if (condition)
{
    EventPointer = Event1;
}
else
{
    EventPointer = Event2;
}

EventPointer.Value //.DoSomething
```